# iOS: test app for iPhone in iPad, screen size

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, iphone-5, iphone-4

I have a stupid question:
Why when I debug an app for iPhone in an iPad the simulation start in a iPhone 4 screen and not in other types of screen?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean the iPad simulate runs with the app and has an option in the bottom right (I think it is) saying `x2`? Or do you mean something else? Its very unclear what your issue is. Can you provide screen shots?

Comment: It's easy, you understood well, when you do it, you have to use a iphone 4 display size, do you know?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, please use this button to choose which one you want to use in simulator :

[image]

when you click you should able to see some list like this :

[image]

If you're not able to see other iOS version you can add them in Xcode/Preferences/Downloads section :

[image]

please let me not if you're not asking this.

Answer (score 0):

To set the App to work on a different size screen you must add that screen size to the LaunchImage asset.

1) Create an splash screen launch image for the size of the iPad you want to use.

2) Import it into your project

3) Open images.xcassets in the Project Navigator

[image]

4) Select LaunchImage

5) Drag and drop the splash screen launch image to the correct iPad asset

[image]

It is very frustrating and seems strange, but the Launch Image size tells the App what dimension it can run on.  Setting image sizes in your screen or using auto layout won't work unless that Launch Image size has a splash screen

Comment: I talked about iPad debug, when you launch an app for iPhone in an iPad the screen size is of iPhone 4, is it right?

Comment: Is it possible to have an iPhone 5 screen size in iPad with iPhone app?

Comment: I think you can launch it on the iPad simulator even though it is an iPhone App.  This problem is more common when you go to a new size iPhone.  For instance when the 5 came out there were a lot of apps that had black bars on the top and bottom because they weren't updated from the 4.  Even if programmatically they were prepared for the 5 with Auto Layout, if the Launch Image wasn't updated they would use the 4 screen size on the 5.  Have you created and added the iPhone 5 or iPad launch image?

Comment: After rereading your question I would say put the iPhone 5 Launch Image in, if that doesn't work, pull the iPhone 4 Launch image.  If that doesn't work pop the iPhone 5 launch image in the iPad launch image spot.  If that doesn't work my guess is that the simulator is defaulting to the 4 size because you are using it in an unsupported way (iPad with code configured for the iPhone) and that is its internal default.

Comment: but what if there is no launch image but a storyboard instead?